# UITableView section index doesn't update

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a table view with alphabetical sections and section index working fine. It is backed by NSFetchedResultsController.

The problem is with the search results table generated over the same data. Search results display correctly, with correct section headers. However the section index alongside the table still displays the full alphabet, even when there is only one section in the table.

I am using separate fetched results controllers for the two tables. The search fetched results controller shows that it has the correct number of sections and its `sectionIndexTitles` array is correct. Still, the table view shows the index from the full table.

I have tried calling `reloadSearchIndexTitles` on the search results table view, but the index still shows the old index. Have also looked into using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`, but if I understand it correctly, that won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand this, but I identified the problem was with my view controller hierarchy. Specifically, I had my table view and table view controller (TVC) embedded in a container view and controller AND the TVC subclassed UITableViewController.

Apple's Table View Programming Guide suggests that in this situation, your TVC should subclass UIViewController, instead. UITableViewController makes assumptions that no longer apply in this situation. Once I made this change, my search index started working properly.